# When i have a space in the input it duplicates

Tags: java

First i want to when they give a wrong input, please thats wrong input wrote there a logical input.

when i press space, for every space it duplicates the replacement.

like

Please enter a delivery speed.

If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.

24 hours

Wrong type, please read options and be careful with the capital letters.

Please enter a delivery speed.

If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.

Wrong type, please read options and be careful with the capital letters.

Please enter a delivery speed.

If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.

123 123 123

Wrong type, please read options and be careful with the capital letters.

Please enter a delivery speed.

If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.

Wrong type, please read options and be careful with the capital letters.

Please enter a delivery speed.

If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.

Wrong type, please read options and be careful with the capital letters.

Please enter a delivery speed.

If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.

Here is my code.

Please help me .

```
   import java.util.InputMismatchException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class deneme123 {
       public static void main(String[] args){
          String opt=null;
          Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
           double cost= 0.0;
          while (true) {
               while (true) {
                   System.out.println("Please enter a delivery speed.\nIf you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.");
                  try {
                      opt = input.next();
                     break;
                 }
                 catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                     System.out.println("Wrong type, pls try again!");
                      input.nextLine();
                  }
              }
              if (opt.equals("fast")) {
                  cost = cost + 34.9;
                 System.out.println("Total is updated to " + cost + "$");
                 break;
              }
              else if (opt.equals("average")) {
                  cost = cost + 17.5;
                  System.out.println("Total is updated to " + cost + "$");
                  break;
              }
              else if (opt.equals("standart")) {
                  cost = cost + 5.5;
                  System.out.println("Total is updated to " + cost + "$");
                 break;
                }
                else if (opt.equals("VIP")||opt.equals("vip")||opt.equals("Vip")) {
                   cost = cost + 50;
                  System.out.println("Total is updated to " + cost + "$");
                  break;
               }
                else if (opt.equals("options")) {
                  System.out.println("* For VIP delivery speed enter 'VIP'. (costs 50 $) " +
                           "\n* For fast delivery speed enter 'fast'. (costs 34.9 $) " +
                           "\n* For average delivery speed enter 'average' (costs 17.5 $)" +
                           "\n* For standart delivey speed enter 'standart' (costs 5.5 $)");
               }
              else {
                   System.out.println("Wrong type, please read options and be careful with the capital letters.");
               }
          }
     }
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do in your inner while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code slightly. Below the code, I've shown the output I get when I run it.

```
package deneme23;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author davec
 */
public class Deneme23 {



       public static void main(String[] args){
          String [] opts=null;
          Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
           double cost= 0.0;
           OUTER:
           while (true) {
               while (true) {
                   System.out.println("Please enter a delivery speed.\nIf you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.");
                   try {
                       String line = input.nextLine();
                       opts = line.split("\\s");
                       break;
                   }
                   catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                       System.out.println("Wrong type, pls try again!");
                       input.nextLine();
                   }
               }switch (opts[0]) {
                   case "fast":
                       cost = cost + 34.9;
                       System.out.println("Total is updated to " + cost + "$");
                       break OUTER;
                   case "average":
                       cost = cost + 17.5;
                       System.out.println("Total is updated to " + cost + "$");
                       break OUTER;
                   case "standart":
                       cost = cost + 5.5;
                       System.out.println("Total is updated to " + cost + "$");
                       break OUTER;
                   case "VIP":
                   case "vip":
                   case "Vip":
                       cost = cost + 50;
                       System.out.println("Total is updated to " + cost + "$");
                       break OUTER;
                   case "options":
                       System.out.println("* For VIP delivery speed enter 'VIP'. (costs 50 $) " +
                               "\n* For fast delivery speed enter 'fast'. (costs 34.9 $) " +
                               "\n* For average delivery speed enter 'average' (costs 17.5 $)" +
                               "\n* For standart delivey speed enter 'standart' (costs 5.5 $)");
                       break;
                   default:
                       System.out.println("Wrong type, please read options and be careful with the capital letters.");
                       break;
               }
           }
     }
    }
```

Here is the output I get when I run it:

```
Please enter a delivery speed.
If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.
24 hours
Wrong type, please read options and be careful with the capital letters.
Please enter a delivery speed.
If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.
options
* For VIP delivery speed enter 'VIP'. (costs 50 $) 
* For fast delivery speed enter 'fast'. (costs 34.9 $) 
* For average delivery speed enter 'average' (costs 17.5 $)
* For standart delivey speed enter 'standart' (costs 5.5 $)
Please enter a delivery speed.
If you want to see all options of delivery speed, enter 'options'.
fast
Total is updated to 34.9$
```

Comment: You need to use the code I suggested instead of this line in your code: "opt = input.next();"

Comment: Also you will probably have to set opt = tokens[0] to get the rest of your code to work.

Comment: i couldn't do it can you make it more understandable ? i am new in coding

Comment: Did you replace "opt = input.next()" in your code with the block of code I suggested?  And did you set "opt = tokens[0]"?  What was the result?

Comment: it didn't work.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at deneme123.main(deneme123.java:6)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Comment: Update your question with the full code that gets the NullPointerException and the input you entered to make it get that exception.

Comment: It turns out that opt has to be redeclared to take the output of the split function.  I have added an answer to this question that should work.  Try it.